# Mysql does not escape & special char

Tags: php, mysql

I m tring to escape the `&` [ampersand] char in mysql query in php,  I tired using:

```
mysql_real_escape_string
mysql_escape_string
mysqli_real_escape_string
```

I want to insert raw html data, here is the data:

```
<h1>Hello&nbsp;<img alt="" src="/images/1000_no%281%29.png" /></h1>
```

The data is broken because of ampersand in above data. I m not able to escape that.

Comment: How would the ampersand disturb your mysql query? Elaborate on what you are actually doing; at least by showing some code.

Comment: @mario mention that query is braking after & sign in data above

Comment: Can we see your query?

Comment: @MT8 Where did you get the "after" from?

Comment: It doesn't because `&` is a safe character for a query. Somewhere else you're html-escaping it

Comment: after means it is not in query.... i mean to say after & symbol it is breaking

Comment: $query="update TestApp_DashboardQuestions set question='".mysql_real_escape_string($value)."' where questionId=1 ";

Comment: em pretty sure you can't pass mysql_real_escape_string($value) in a query,remove quotes around mysql_real_escape_string($value)

Comment: Your insert query is perfectly fine. You have a display issue somewhere else. Nobody will be able to answer unless you provide *significant* more details and a visualization of what "data is broken" means to you.

Answer (score 0):

```
$all_html_content=mysql_real_escape_string($all_html_content);
```

You have put string values inside single quotes:

```
$insert_query = "insert into table_name values('$all_html_content');";
```

Comment: The `&` will still passes untouched (as it has to), OP issue must be in the code he didn't post

Answer (score 0):

As others has stated, there must be another issue that would be revealed in your code that we cannot see.  Below is proof that you can insert the desired HTML into a table without the need for escaping:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cd566/1

Hope this helps.